# How do I remove the white text boxes, black text, and brick wall from this picture?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

As you can see, I have tried using the spot healing and healing brush tools as well as magic wand + fill to no avail.

[image]

Comment: The original drawing was allmost certainly vector its trivial to delete in that. Do you have the original? If not it takes very little time to redraw (atleast for me say 30 minutes to be on the safe side)

Comment: I ended up recreating a nicer version of the image

Answer (score 0):

You can try clone stamp brush and/or patch tool with content aware.
Also you can outline with pen tool selection and use brush. There is a little gradient there so you have to be careful where you pick the colour with eyedropper tool.

Comment: Thanks for the attempt and also, I do not see a difference between that stamp brush and the healing brush

Comment: They are very different. You just have to get used to it. It's like how a painter knows the difference between two brushes. Yes, both brush puts the paint on the canvas but a painter knows which one would give which kind of effect.

Answer (score -1):

Selecting the unwanted areas: 
1. Magic Wand (W)
2. Polygon Lasso (L)
3. Delete

You can re-create the black connecting lines if you want.

Comment: The issue about this is that selecting the unwanted areas and deleting or filling it with content aware creates a mess.  Recreation of the lines seems like it is necessary as you said, but I still don't really know how to do that

Comment: Never delete anything, if you can avoid it.  Always work non-destructively and instead use a layer mask to hide what you want to delete instead.